# Enable category only for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, categories

I have iPhone and iPad project. I use some UINavigationBar category for iPhone. On iPad it not works. I want to disable it. How can I enable it on for iPhone?

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size{
size.width = self.frame.size.width;
size.height = 90;
return size;
}
```

Comment: So you are saying that the mere existence of the sizeThatFits: method causes a problem on the iPad? Keep in mind that it is a very BAD idea to override existing methods in a category. You really shouldn't do this at all.

Comment: How then I can increase height for navigationBar can you help me?

Comment: Try setting its frame. You are providing no useful info in your question. How is the navigation bar created/added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your category is redefining a base class method you should use subclassing and only use the new class for the iPhone. If you're adding new functionality you could use a MACRO such like IS-IPAD which you'd define reading the device idiom and make conditional execution for iPhone - iPad

Comment: I believe they are asking how to do this. Without detailing how (With code) I would say this is an incomplete answer.

Comment: I'll post the full code I recommend to use soon so it could be more complete. Right now I'm only in my iPhone

Comment: That's fine it just seemed incomplete that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to do this, but, generally when you have a project that involves both iPhone and iPad, if there is differences in code then you would have 3 classes.

- ClassBase
- ClassIPhone : ClassBase
- ClassIPad : ClassBase

and you would simply import the category into your ClassIPhone class and not your ClassIPad class